# creating a Java completion object such that consumers can wait for logical combinations of these objects

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm working on a scriptable object model that includes completion objects for asynchronous computation, such that end-user scripts can wait upon logical combinations of the completion objects. The problem is that if I use the builtin monitor objects via `wait()` and `notify()`/`notifyAll()` then [there's no mechanism for waiting for multiple objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265225/java-how-can-a-thread-wait-on-multiple-objects); if I use [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) it's unclear how to compose more than one object.

I want something like this:

```
/** object representing the state of completion of an operation
  * which is initially false, then becomes true when the operation completes */
interface Completion
{
    /** returns whether the operation is complete */
    public boolean isDone();
    /** waits until the operation is complete */
    public void await() throws InterruptedException;
}

class SomeObject
{
    public Completion startLengthyOperation() { ... } 
}

class Completions
{
    public Completion or(Completion ...objects);
    public Completion and(Completion ...objects);
}
```

so that a script or end-application can do this:

```
SomeObject obj1, obj2, obj3;
... /* assign obj1,2,3 */
Completion c1 = obj1.startLengthOperation();
Completion c2 = obj2.startLengthOperation();
Completion c3 = obj3.startLengthOperation();
Completion anyOf = Completions.or(c1,c2,c3);
Completion allOf = Completions.and(c1,c2,c3);
anyOf.await();  // wait for any of the 3 to be finished
... // do something
allOf.await();  // wait for all of the 3 to be finished
... // do something else
```

The `and()` case is easy to handle if I implement using `CountDownLatch` -- I just wait for all of them in any sequence. But how can I handle the `or()` case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like [Guava's `ListenableFuture`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html), or at least like you should adapt some of the ideas.  The key point is to be able to add listeners for the completion of a thing.  At that point, the implementation is fairly straightforward: you just create a `Completion` object and add listeners to each of the target `Completion`s to mark the `or` `Completion` as complete.

Comment: Hmm. If my end-users were using Java I would agree. But these are people using a scripting language (I'm exposing my object model using JSR223), who are inexperienced with the subtleties of concurrency, and I need to make a simple interface for them to wait for something.

Comment: ... [thinks a bit] ... do you mean for *end-users* to implement listeners, or *me* to implement listeners as a way of getting there?

Comment: I mean for you to implement listeners as a way of getting there.

Comment: hey, it worked (using listeners to propagate state to a derived completion object)! thanks!